# J2EE Mybatis webapp on Java 8 - java.lang.RuntimeException: XPathFactory#newInstance

Tags: java, spring, xslt, mybatis

Our J2EE/Spring/Mybatis web application has been running fine for some time on Java 7 (on Centos), but recently we tried updating our JVM to Java 8, and now we get the following stack-trace on start up:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: XPathFactory#newInstance() 
 failed to create an XPathFactory for the default object model:
 http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom with the XPathFactoryConfigurationException: javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryConfigurationException: 
 java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:jar:file:/usr/local/tomcats
/test/webapps/tms/WEB-INF/lib/saxon-xpath-8.7.jar!/META-INF/services/javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:2: Illegal configuration-file syntax
    at javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance(XPathFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.ibatis.parsing.XPathParser.commonConstructor(XPathParser.java:261)
    at org.apache.ibatis.parsing.XPathParser.<init>(XPathParser.java:121)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.<init>(XMLMapperBuilder.java:75)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.<init>(XMLMapperBuilder.java:70)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.annotation.MapperAnnotationBuilder.loadXmlResource(MapperAnnotationBuilder.java:158)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.annotation.MapperAnnotationBuilder.parse(MapperAnnotationBuilder.java:113)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperRegistry.addMapper(MapperRegistry.java:66)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.addMapper(Configuration.java:651)
    at org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean.checkDaoConfig(MapperFactoryBean.java:97)
```

our Saxon9.jar version = 9.1.0.8 (latest).

There are many different jars/dependencies involved in parsing xml/xslt in our application, and I don't want to try guessing what changes to make by trial and error.  Does anyone know what could be causing this, or where to look first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is described [here](https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/1944).
If you want to use Saxon with Java 8 you need to upgrade Saxon to a version >= 9.5.1.5

Comment: thanks for that - incidentally do you know whether Saxon changed to a 'freemium' model when they moved 9.1 -> 9.5 ?

Comment: sorry, don't know, i am not very familiar with saxons licensing models

Comment: I found you don't necessarily have to update from Saxon 9.1 B..  the offending class is not resident in the main jar, but in the auxiliary saxon-xpath.jar
If your project doesn’t utilise XPath expressions from Java, simply omit this jar from the class path - all XSLT transformation functionality seems to still work fine